# No email in graph results, but shows it in Graph API Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have email in my scope, i see the app has email permissions given, but no email in results, yet if i use the explorer with the apps access token, i get the email. 
This is driving me crazy I am sure i have all correct.

```
    Return Redirect(String.Format("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&scope=email&redirect_uri={1}&state={2}", My.Resources.FacebookApiKey, My.Resources.FacebookRedirectUrl, Session.SessionID))


Dim webRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim targetURI As New Uri(String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_secret={2}&code={3}&scope=email", My.Resources.FacebookApiKey, My.Resources.FacebookRedirectUrl, My.Resources.FacebookApiSecret, code))
        webRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(targetURI), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        If (webRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength > 0) Then
            Dim str As New System.IO.StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            reply = str.ReadToEnd
            str.Close()
        End If

        Dim replies As String() = Split(reply, "=")
        targetURI = New Uri(String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}", replies(1)))
        webRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(targetURI), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        If (webRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength > 0) Then
            Dim str As New System.IO.StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            reply = str.ReadToEnd
            str.Close()
        End If
```

If you can shine some light i would be most happy.

Comment: You might wanna subscribe to this bug report  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/428191153870147

Answer (score 0):

I'm no .net programmer, but if the email is the only thing that's missing, you could try adding a query string to your request URL, like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}&fields=email
```

It should work fine and return the email address in a JSON object:

```
{
  "email": "user.name@gmail.com",
  "id": "12312312312313123123",
  "type": "user"
}
```